# Post to topic and Manual commit in spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

We are working on a requirement where the Spring-kafka consumer is committing to a topic and then should manually commit the offset.

One of the scenario that we are thinking is what happens when the consumer fails between the time that it  submits the message to the topic and before the offset is manually committed. In such a scenario the application will reprocess the message and submit one more time resulting in duplicate messages in the topic.

Is there any way that both the activities can be part of a TransactionManager, so that it success/fails all  ?

Configuration file

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, User> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("trans");
    //defaultKafkaProducerFactory.transactionCapable();
    return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    //return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}


@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager<String, User> transactionManager() {
    KafkaTransactionManager transactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory());
    transactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS);
    transactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
    return transactionManager;
}


/**
 * New configuration for the consumerFactory added
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "firstTopic-group");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<User>(User.class));
}


@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, User>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.setRetryTemplate(kafkaRetry());
    factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    factory.setErrorHandler(getErrorHandler());
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(retryContext -> {
        //implement the logic to decide the action after all retries are over.
        ConsumerRecord consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord) retryContext.getAttribute("record");
        System.out.println("Recovery is called for message  " + consumerRecord.value());
        return Optional.empty();
    });

    return factory;
}



public RetryTemplate kafkaRetry() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(60 * 1000);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(3);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(4 * 60 * 1000);       // original 25 * 60 * 1000
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(4);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}


public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException,
                           List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                           Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                           MessageListenerContainer container) {
            //super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
            if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
                String topic = record.topic();
                long offset = record.offset();
                int partition = record.partition();

                if (thrownException instanceof DeserializationException) {
                    System.out.println("------1111------deserialization exception ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("------xxxx------Record is empty ");
                    consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("------4444------Record is empty ");
            }

        }
    };

    return errorHandler;
}
```

Kafka listener

```
   @Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;


@KafkaListener(topics = "firstTopic", groupId = "firstTopic-group")
@Transactional
public void onCustomerMessage(User user, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {

    /*System.out.println("get the message " +user.getFirstName());
    if (user.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase("Test")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Incompatible message " + user.getFirstName());
    }
    */

    //postToSecondTopic(acknowledgment, user);

    System.out.println("NOT In transaction");
    kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(t -> {
        System.out.println("---------------------->");
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        t.send("secondtopic", user);
        if (number % 5 == 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        return true;
    });


    System.out.println("*** exit ***");
}
```

Error in the logs

2020-05-28 15:52:53.597 ERROR 112469 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:216) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.barade.sandesh.springKafka.UserResource.postComments(UserResource.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]

UserResource

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("accounts")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate <String, User> kafkaTemplate;


    @PostMapping("/users")
    public String postComments(@RequestParam ("firstName") final String firstName,
                                    @RequestParam ("lastName") final String lastName,
                                    @RequestParam ("userName") final String userName )  {

        List<String> accountTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        kafkaTemplate.send("firstTopic", new User(firstName,lastName,userName));

        return "Message sent to the Error queue";
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; see [Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions).

The container starts the transaction, any `KafkaTemplate` send operations in the listener participate in the transaction; the container sends the offset(s) to the transaction and commits (if the listener exits normally).

There is no need to "manually" commit the offset.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the quick response.  In our case the listener reads from one topic and then writes to another topic.  if it is NOT a manual commit  and  listenser errors out after the msg is pushed to the second topic , how will the offset be committed  ?  wouldnt it restart and process the same message and try to post it again   ?

Comment: I was looking at the link you provided and was wondering if KafkaTransactionManager can be leveraged for this

Comment: Yes; when using the `KafkaTransactionManager`, if the listener throws an exception the transaction is rolled back and the `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` re-seeks the records so the same record will be replayed. You can configure the after rollback processor to send a record that keeps failing to a dead-letter topic. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#after-rollback and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters

Comment: From the transactions link , i  tried to use Kafkatemplate  to run my transactions. I added 
defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("tx-");

My code is  [link]https://github.com/sandeshbarade/springKafka
I get this error 
2020-05-27 19:31 ERROR  [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation

Comment: For producer-initiated transactions (e.g. from from a web controller), you must either annotate the method with `@Transactional` (with the `KafkaTransactionManager` or use `template.executeInTransaction()`. To use `@Transactional` you need `@EnableTransactionManagement` on a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Thanks Gary, apologies for asking about the same question. I am using KafkaTransactionManager by setting it in the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory   and created a bean for it. After that my server fails to restart

Comment: Error i get :    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/barade/sandesh/springKafka/config/KakfaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is or

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question and add the full, complete, stack trace.

Comment: You need to show `com.barade.sandesh.springKafka.UserResource.postComments`. Also, you don't need both `@Transactional` and `executeInTransaction` in the `@KafkaListener`. The first is redundant since the container will start a transaction; the `executeInTransaction` means start a new transaction and don't use the existing one.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your inputs. I have added the UserResource (it also has a KafkaTemplate autowired).  I removed the @Transactional from the listener yet get the same error.

Comment: You are not starting a transaction in the `UserResource.postComments`. As the error message says, you either need `@Transactional` on that method, or `kafkaTemplate.send("firstTopic", new User(firstName,lastName,userName));` needs to be called within `executeInTransaction()`.

Comment: Thanks alot gary it worked. I didnt realize that I was placing the @Transactonal at incorrect location